# Using my user account to create sns and cloudwatch resources in root account using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to create sns billing alarm using cloudwatch when the cost reaches a particular threshold, I can do this manually but I'm trying to use terraform. Hello, I'm a NEWBIE to terraform, when I create this using terraform it's been created in the user account, I tried using the root Access keys but it continues to create them in my user account. Now, i'm not sure maybe i'm assuming wrong, when i create the billing alarm on the management console i do it using root account.
Here is my code:

```
provider "aws" {
  shared_config_files      = ["/mnt/c/Users/{user}/.aws/config"]
  shared_credentials_files = ["/mnt/c/Users/{user}/.aws/credentials"]
  profile                  = "root"
  #  region  = "us-east-2"
}
```

```
module "sns_topic" {
  source = "/mnt/c/terraform-ansible-automate/sns"

  aws_account_id = var.aws_account_id
  aws_env        = var.aws_env
  email          = var.email
}
```

```
module "cloudwatch" {
  source = "/mnt/c/terraform-ansible-automate/cloudwatch"
  #  source = "/cloudwatch"

  monthly_billing_threshold = var.monthly_billing_threshold
  sns_topic_arn             = [module.sns_topic.sns_cost_alert_topic_arn]
  aws_account_id            = var.aws_account_id
  aws_env                   = var.aws_env
}
```

Comment: What is the issue here? Are there any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please verify in which account are you authenticated while running your terraform code?

Use the below command:

```bash
## It assumes that you have aws CLI pre-installed.
aws sts get-caller-identity
```

If you are already logged in the root account (desired account) it should work normally but if you are in any other account (user account in your case).

It could be because of the IAM user/role being used for the terraform authentication being in that account.
And then you have two choices in general.

- Either assume a role in the desired account from the current signed/logged-in user. The role must have a trust relationship(policy) between your logged-in User. (your User should be allowed to assume that role from another account). The role being assumed must also have the required permissions(policies attached) on the desired account to make the required changes.

Please look into Hashicorp Documentation on [provision-resource-across-aws-accounts](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/tutorials/aws/aws-assumerole#provision-resource-across-aws-accounts)

From the code perspective, you can refer to https://github.com/ishuar/stackoverflow-terraform/tree/main/aws/user_with_programmatic_access_assume_role/user_assuming_role_with_policies_attached as an example on How to Use IAM User to Assume Role with Required Access.

> This is not a cross-account example but it is similar only need to adjust the role_arn in the provider block of [instance_and_sg_creation](https://github.com/ishuar/stackoverflow-terraform/blob/main/aws/user_with_programmatic_access_assume_role/user_assuming_role_with_policies_attached/instance_and_sg_creation/providers.tf)

- Use an IAM user that already exists in the desired account with having required permissions. Use the secrets for that user in your terraform authentication and make the changes. This is like any normal terraform code execution.

Comment: After using the '''aws sts get-caller-identity''' i got this: '''{
    "UserId": "AIDA2BN4Q4WLXEHAXF3IF",
    "Account": "{{account-id}}",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::{{account-id}}:user/Kunle"
}''', it's also important to let you know the user already has Admin role attached to it, so I'm confused about what I'm missing.

Comment: is the account which you got in the results is the same account ID where you want to deploy these resources? Also, the signed user has permission to assume a role in that account?

Comment: No, it's not, there is the ROOT account and there is the ADMIN account "KUNLE". I created the SNS topic and Cloudwatch first using the ADMIN user Kunle's credentials, when the SNS topic was created, it did it in the ADMIN user account but I wanted it in the ROOT user account, I changed the credentials to the ROOT user account and still got the SNS topic and Cloudwatch created in the ADMIN users account.